# How to build docker image from manifest and blob files

Tags: docker, nexus, docker-registry

I have some Docker images that I exported from a Docker registry (said registry is no longer available though so I can't export them in another format). The files were exported in the following format:

```
blobs
    sha123423xv
    sha1234234sdfas
    ...
folder1
    folder1a
        manifest1
    folder1b
        manifest2
    ...
```

I assume that the blobs represent the layers of the docker images. That folder is 40GB in size making me confident that all the data is there.

However, I am unsure of how to get docker images out of the manifests again.
I know about the docker load command but that one requires me to have a .zip with the manifest and all relevant layers (as far as I understand it).

My problem: I have the manifests in separate folders (one for each docker image) but the blobs are all in one big folder with just checksums (i.e. SHAadsfasdf) as names. How do I make working docker images out of this again?

Thanks
Robin

PS: The files were created using a Nexus Repository export task: https://help.sonatype.com/repomanager3/nexus-repository-administration/tasks/repository-export

Comment: Can you `docker load` the combined tar file?  Is there any code working with this, or is this more of an administration task of recovering the previous registry?

Comment: Presumably that export is designed to be used with the nexus import utility: https://help.sonatype.com/repomanager3/nexus-repository-administration/tasks/repository-import. If you convert that file structure into an OCI Layout (https://github.com/opencontainers/image-spec/blob/main/image-layout.md), there are other tools that can work directly with that.